# Fetching information from a web page and and writing into a .xls file using pandas and bs4

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner to Python Programming. I am practicing web scraping using bs4 module in python.

I have extracted some fields from a web page but but while I try to write them into an .xls file, the .xls file remains empty except the headings.
Kindly tell where am I doing wrong and if possible suggest what is to be done.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://rwbj.com.au/find-an-agent.html')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"fluidgrid-cell fluidgrid-cell-2"})

records = []
name =[]
phone =[]
email=[]
title=[]
location=[]
for item in data:
    name = item.find('h3',class_='heading').text.strip()
    phone = item.find('a',class_='text text-link text-small').text.strip()
    email = item.find('a',class_='text text-link text-small')['href']
    title = item.find('div',class_='text text-small').text.strip()
    location = item.find('div',class_='text text-small').text.strip()

    records.append({'Names': name, 'Title': title, 'Email': email, 'Phone': phone, 'Location': location})

df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Title','Phone','Email','Location'])
df=df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\R&W.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use selenium, then you can make the same post request web page makes. This will give you an `xml` response, which you can parse using `Beautifulsoup` to get the output you need.

We can use the network tab in the inspect tool to get the request being made as well as the form data for this request.

[image]

Next we have to make the same request using `python-requests` and the parse the output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
number_of_agents_required=20 # they only have 20 on the site
payload={
'act':'act_fgxml',
'15[offset]':0,
'15[perpage]':number_of_agents_required,
'require':0,
'fgpid':15,
'ajax':1
}
records=[]
r=requests.post('https://www.rwbj.com.au/find-an-agent.html',data=payload)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
for row in soup.find_all('row'):
    name=row.find('name').text
    title=row.position.text.replace('&amp;','&')
    email=row.email.text
    phone=row.phone.text
    location=row.office.text
    records.append([name,title,email,phone,location])
df=pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Title','Phone','Email','Location'])
df.to_excel('R&W.xls', sheet_name='MyData2', index = False, header=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Weirdly I didn't see this show up when answering.  +1 for better approach.

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly. Kindly if you can explain me the working of the above code. In the Element tab, I could not find the 'row' tag. Even the reason for using '&amp' and '&'. Kindly if you can explain your code as I am a beginner to Python programming and I want to learn more about this method.  The code part if you can kindly explain : ````for row in soup.find_all('row'):
    name=row.find('name').text
    title=row.position.text.replace('&amp;','&')
    email=row.email.text
    phone=row.phone.text
    location=row.office.text ````

Comment: @ag2019 If you `print(soup)` you can see the `xml` response. The code means - for each `row` tag in the xml, get the text within the `name`,`title`,`email`,`phone`,`office` tags and save them into the variable on the left side.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for explaining me. Here we set the 'number_of_agent' as 20 as we can see 20 agents in the website but if the web page has many more agents which will take time to count, then what value will we assign the variable 'number_of_agent'?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method like selenium to allow for javascript rendering of content. You can then grab the page_source to continue with your script. I have deliberately kept with your script and only added the new lines for the wait for content.

You could run selenium headless or switch to use HTMLSession instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://rwbj.com.au/find-an-agent.html')

WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3")))

soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
d.quit()
data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"fluidgrid-cell fluidgrid-cell-2"})

records = []
name =[]
phone =[]
email=[]
title=[]
location=[]
for item in data:
    name = item.find('h3',class_='heading').text.strip()
    phone = item.find('a',class_='text text-link text-small').text.strip()
    email = item.find('a',class_='text text-link text-small')['href']
    title = item.find('div',class_='text text-small').text.strip()
    location = item.find('div',class_='text text-small').text.strip()
    records.append({'Names': name, 'Title': title, 'Email': email, 'Phone': phone, 'Location': location})

df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Title','Phone','Email','Location'])
print(df)
```

---

I might consider, depending on if all items were present for each person, something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.headless = True

d = webdriver.Chrome(options = options) 
d.get('https://rwbj.com.au/find-an-agent.html')

WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3")))

soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
d.quit()
names = [item.text for item in soup.select('h3')]
titles = [item.text for item in soup.select('h3 ~ div:nth-of-type(1)')]
tels = [item.text for item in soup.select('h3 + a')]
emails = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('h3 ~ a:nth-of-type(2)')]
locations = [item.text for item in soup.select('h3 ~ div:nth-of-type(2)')]      
records = list(zip(names, titles, tels, emails, positions))
df = pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['Names','Title','Phone','Email','Location'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Okay I will try to learn Selenium now, but could you please tell me the reason behind the not allowing to from extract information from a web page.

Comment: the page updates content via xhr requests. You either need to make requests to that url or use selenium to allow time for the content to render.